# 4NEC2 - Antenna outside Pattern

Tags: antenna, antenna-modeling

I am very new to 4Nec2 and need to do a simulation of a half-wave dipole antenna for 433 MHz. I've read a couple of tutorials and I understand most of it so far, still, my simulation doesn't make sense.
As you can see, the antenna is outside the pattern. Using the editor, I lifted both ends up 1 meter (on the Z-Axis). The pattern is still around the origin.

Anyone knows why?

[image: Simulation]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The displayed radiation pattern is not a physical object in a meaningful spatial relation to the elements of the antenna, it's a graph of data. Consider the meaning of the (polar) coordinates of each:

- For the antenna model, $(r, \phi, \theta)$ are coordinates of the antenna structure elements.
- For the pattern graph, $(\phi, \theta)$ specify a *direction* away from the antenna, and $r$ is a *gain value*, not a length.

Remember, when you are modeling an antenna like this you are considering the *far field* results — the pattern is telling you the radiated power that would pass through a given point *infinitely far away* from the physical antenna structure.

To make spatial sense of the pattern, if you must, you can think of it like your antenna model is “shrunk to a point”, made infinitely small. And the point it's shrunk to might as well be the coordinate origin, not the center of your entered model, because that's simple and well-defined, and there's no particular guarantee that your antenna model is symmetric to *have* a well-defined center.